# Showing a function is not continuous in the one-norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I have the following question:

> Consider the normed space $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$. Let $x_{0}\in [0,1]$ and define $F:C([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ by
>
> $F(f)=f(x_{0})$
>
> Show that $F$ is discontinuous with respect to $||\cdot||_{1}$.

I realise that I simply need to find a counterexample where $f_{n}\to f$ with respect to the one-norm, but where $F(f_{n})\not \to F(f)$.  However, I see no way in which to do this. I hate being lazy with this so would appreciate a small push in the right direction.

Comment: There are some very simple, familiar functions $f_n$ that are $0$ at $0$, $1$ at $1$, and squeezing towards the $x$-axis as $n$ increases. They give you a nice example when $x_0=1$. For other values of $x_0$ you can adapt the basic idea of that family, most easily by using piecewise linear functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question and you mean $L^1$ norm (you also mention sup norm and $F$ is continuous with respect to that, which is perhaps point of problem), you could let $f_n$ be $0$ on $[0,1/2-1/n^2]$, the line from $0$ to $n$ on $[1/2-1/n^2,1/2]$, the line from $n$ to $0$ on $[1/2,1/2+1/n^2]$, and $0$ on $[1/2+1/n^2]$.  Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^1$, but $F(f_n)=n$.

Basically any function that is zero except for a "high spike of small area" will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.  Squeeze a bump.

Comment: -1, you could keep these ideas that are relatively small enough for an answer as a comment.

Comment: Actually that is an answer. I am trying to avoid "giving away the shop."